# Can I switch to another process in another tty# terminal from an ssh terminal?

Tags: ssh, tty

Here's the deal. I have a Linux Mint 15 server running a web server, an ssh server, and a minecraft server. When I go back to college after the summer, I want to leave my machine at home (6 hrs away) and just ssh in when I need to do things. I use the tty1 terminal to execute the minecraft server (always), and it constantly prints log info and accepts input from the server (this can change things in game, edit and reload the whitelist, and a few other things).

So, is there a way for me to legitimately (or even by "hacking") ssh into my computer and then take control of another tty# terminal and inject my own commands into a process it is running as well as view that process's output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best and easiest way is to use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) or gnu [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  Both let you detach a session and pick it up from another terminal, among their other nice features.

Comment: tmux is perfect. It took me all of five minutes to get it working.